# How to check if an object is null

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
public static class SerializationUtil
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return string.Empty;

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter().Serialize(writer, obj);
        return writer.ToString();
    }

    public static object Deserialize(string data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return null;
        return (new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter()).Deserialize(data);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is: When I call the serialize method if the obj is null it throws an error. So i would like to check if the obj value is null or not. The code I have i place now does not work as when the obj value is checked its never null.

**Resolved:**

See my post in answers

Comment: Exactly where is the exception thrown? Do you have the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: it is thrown at new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter().Serialize(writer, obj);

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Can you also put in the exception details including the stack trace in the post as Fredrik suggested?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but since `Serialize` generates an empty string instead of null, perhaps `Deserialize` should accept an empty string in addition to null.

Comment: @Luke101: How can you have an exception at System.Web.UI.LosFormatter().Serialize(writer, obj); when you have already checked for null? Can you check for the actual content of the obj? Or can you provide the actual error details (possibly the stack trace)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have figured it out. I looked at the details of the exception and it expected the object class to be serializable. I made the class serializable and it worked

```
using System;

[Serializable]  //the missing piece
public class RegisterFormData
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string pass1 { get; set; }
    public string pass2 { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you know, I was going to suggest that in the comments, and then thougth it couldn't possibly be because of that, could it?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think that what you're describing is possible. If you've checked that `obj` is not null only a few lines above, then it is not null. If you're getting a `NullReferenceException` it is likely due to something *else* being null, possibly within the `Serialize` method itself.